# SetUp is not called in DUnitX in Rad Studio

Tags: c++builder, dunitx

I have built the example for DUnitX for Rad Studio Berlin in C++.
The code is a copy of : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/DUnitX_Overview

The header is:

```
 class __declspec(delphirtti) TestCalc : public TObject
 {
  public:
    virtual void __fastcall SetUp();
    virtual void __fastcall TearDown();

  __published:
     void __fastcall TestAdd();
     void __fastcall TestSub();
  };
```

TestAdd and TestSub are called because they are under __published, but SetUp and TearDown are never called. I understand that they should be called for each test. Seeing the Delphi code, I can see the [Setup] attribute but it seems that for C++ is not necessary. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same Problem.

As a workaround I developed a little helper class:

```
template <typename T>
class TestEnviroment{
public:
    TestEnviroment(T* theTest)
        :itsTest(theTest)
    { itsTest->SetUp(); }

    ~TestEnviroment() { itsTest->TearDown(); }

private:
    T* itsTest;
};
```

Which is the first local variable in every test case:

```
void __fastcall UnitTest::Test()
{
    TestEnviroment<UnitTest> testenv{this};

    // TODO Testing
}
```

Comment: After a little more usage of Dunitx in CppBuilder I advise to use instead the Dunit (without X). Delphi Attributes, which are heavily used by Dunitx but not by Dunit are not supported by CppBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that fixes this problem is to override the two virtual methods bellow of the TObject base class:

```
virtual void __fastcall AfterConstruction(void);
__fastcall virtual ~TTestCalc(void);
```

The first method is executed after the object was created and calls SetUp and the second method overrides the virtual destructor to call TearDown.

Complete solution:

```
class __declspec(delphirtti) TTestCalc : public TObject
{
public:
    __fastcall virtual ~TTestCalc();
    virtual void __fastcall AfterConstruction();
    virtual void __fastcall SetUp();
    virtual void __fastcall TearDown();

__published:
    void __fastcall TestAdd();
    void __fastcall TestSub();
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall TTestCalc::~TTestCalc()
{
TearDown();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TTestCalc::AfterConstruction()
{
SetUp();
TObject::AfterConstruction();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Other methods ...
```

Answer (score 0):

*use*:

> class __declspec(delphirtti) TestCalc : public **TTestCase**

*instead of*:

> class __declspec(delphirtti) TestCalc : public `**TObject**